# Laravel migrate not working on new database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I just uninstalled and installed back again MySQL via brew in Mac OS X High Sierra. I created back a db for my Laravel project, then made sure the name of the db matched the one in the .env, but when running:

> php artisan migrate

nothing's happening. I tried also

> php artisan migrate -vvv

but I've got the same result: nothing! No output, no errors indicating what might be wrong.

Any indication will be appreciated.

Comment: There is an another problem for sure. At least it says "nothing to migrate". But you can try with php artisan migrate --force

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: @AliÖzen I did try --force, but nothing comes up

Comment: @Jerodev yes, nothing relevant

Comment: can you check your database config that its consuming .env data?

Comment: then try php artisan cache:clear; php artisan config:clear; php artisan config:cache;

Comment: @AliÖzen just tried what you suggested but nothing happened

Comment: Can you please tell, that new database contain migration table ?

Comment: @user3888958 no, I simply created the database with no tables, then proceeded to run the migration

Comment: is there any error, while you run php artisan migrate command ?

Comment: @user3888958 no erros at all, nothing appears. I tried to get some output by executing -vvv but nothing happened

Comment: Did you try **composer dump-autoload** command ?

Comment: @user3888958 yes I did, same result

Comment: Have you tried `php migrate:status` to see which migrations are to be run? Have your tried `php artisan migrate:fresh`?

Comment: @kerbholz yes sir, I did try both and got the same results. No output at all, it hangs

Answer (score 0):

You can clear cache using this commad
php artisan cache:clear
and then you can use php artisan migrate
Try this I hope this will help you!

Comment: users table migration first. If you are in development and don't need to keep your data, you can just delete the users table and then run php artisan migrate
Try this

Comment: I simply created the database with no tables, then proceeded to run the migration. You're telling me that I should run first the users' table migration?

Comment: So I just ran: php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php but I'm getting nothing yet

Comment: Yes. 
And check once /database/migrations/ have files for migrate

Comment: I do have files, just checked. Running users migration didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you do and in my case I didn't had password set for db user which caused this issue. Try the following:

- Assign password to the db user using `mysqladmin -u YOURDBUSER password 'newpassword'`
- If it still doesn't work after assigning password to the user, try granting that user all permissions (I don't advise this for production use) `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON yourDB.* to 'YOURUSER'@'localhost';`

Good luck.